# Given a contentEditable Div how to set the cursor to a specific position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

Given a contentEditable div like so:

```
<div contenteditable="true">Here is some text, hello world.</div>
```

How can I set the cursor at position 6, right after the s in is?

I've been trying to use:

```
savedRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
```

And then modify the values like so:

```
savedRange.startOffset = 6
savedRange.endOffset = 6
```

But that isn't updating the savedRange.

Any ideas how I can get the cursor/caret in the div? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's position 7. Anyway, here's how, assuming you give your editable `<div>` an id of "myDiv". Note this won't work in IE < 9, which has a completely different range and selection API.

```
if (window.getSelection) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var textNode = document.getElementById("myDiv").firstChild;
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(textNode, 7);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up needing to make my contenteditable have <div contenteditable="true"><p>Here is some text,<span class="tagged"> hello world.</span></p></div> .... Given a span, how can I get that and set it as the textNode?

Comment: `range.selectNodeContents(referenceToYourSpan)`. Beyond that, I'd suggest reading about ranges. MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range) is pretty good. There's also the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#interface-range) if you're feeling brave.

Comment: Thanks Tim, what do you mean by referenceToYourSpan?

Comment: @AnApprentice: A variable that refers to the `<span>` element. E.g. `var referenceToYourSpan = document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByTagName("span")[0];`